# Is there any way to define a "Service Contributor" role per API?

Tags: azure-api-management

I like to have `User-A` can contribute to the `API-A` but doesn't have access to the `API-B`.

When I look at the Azure APIM Built-in roles (link below) I am noticing that the `API Management Service Contributor` role is defined for all APIs.

Is it possible to to define a "Service Contributor" role per API as opposed with all  APIS?
If not, is there any other technique that help me to achieve the same goal

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can restrict the user to specific set of APIs.

**1) Through Product Level where you can add the APIs and allow all APIS to the specific set of users by keeping the Scope level to Product for the users**.

1. Created 2 different APIs in APIM Instance like the below:
   [image]
2. Open the New APIM Developer Portal after adding the APIs and publish the APIM instance > Portal Overview under Developer Portal.
3. In APIM Instance > Products > Added new product "Dotnet6FunctionAPIs" - Added the Net 6 Function App APIs > Checked the options "Requires Subscription", "Requires approval" and then published the product.

[image]
4. In APIM Instance > Users - created a user and in Products > Dotnet6FunctionAPIs Product > Access control > Allowed the access to Developers group.

5. Login to the developer portal with the new user login credentials `https://<apiminstance_name>.portal.azure-api.net/` > Products > Dotnet6FunctionAPIs product > Click on Subscribe.

[image]

Here the Admin can approve the access of that product APIs to the user and can cancel the subscription whenever admin wants to.

After Subscription approval, the user can test the API present in the product.
[image]

If you observe here, I have allowed the users (under Developer group) to the product "**`Dotnet6FunctionAPIs`**" that contains specific APIs added to it.

This is one of the ways to restrict users from not accessing the other APIs by adding only specific APIs to the product and giving that product access to the users.

#### Updated Answer:

As Markus told, there are 3 built-in roles in APIM. `API Management Service Contributor` is for CRUD access to Complete APIM Instance (all APIS & Operations) and cannot be restricted to specific APIs.
I have seen the permissions given to `API Management Service Contributor` built-in role. Among those permissions, I believe we need to modify at API Policy Level which is
`Write (Access) - Set API policy configuration (Permissions) - Creates or updates policy configuration for the API`.

[image: APIMServiceContributorRolePermissionsLookup]

Comment: ok, but `User-A` is still able to modify `API-B` in Azure Portal.  But `User-A` is not allowed to use `API-B` in Developer Portal

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, could you please correct that my 1st way suits the requirement I believe, adding specific APIs to the products and allowing users to that product to access that specific APIs?

Comment: I believe the requirement is about changing e.g. the policy of an API in Azure Portal. The [mentioned role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-role-based-access-control) is only valid for the Azure Portal for the entire API Management instance: _ Super user. Has full CRUD access to API Management services and entities (for example, APIs and policies). Has access to the legacy publisher portal._  This can not be limited to specific APIs

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. This is not about restricting the consumer of the API. This is about Azure portal administrators.  Consider my point on "API Management Service Contributor" role.

Comment: My bad, Got the requirement. Updated the answer!